# Visual Studio 2008 closes unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I don't know if I can really get an answer to this question, but it really irks me and I would like to know if someone has an idea how to arrive to an answer.

I have a pretty large solution in VS 2008 that maybe every week/every other week whenever I click properties to get to the project properties the IDE closes without warning. After that happens it will close **EVERY** time I try and view the properties. At that point I try and delete the .suo file, I resize the IDE, I close the tabs within the project, I restore default VS Settings(when I'm desperate). Eventually 20-30 minutes later I can actually view the properties. I haven't figured out exactly what fixes it, seems to be different every time. Once it's "fixed" I can't break it again so I can figure out what "fixed" it.

This seems to be project specific, because I can view properties of other projects while this project is misbehaving.

I guess my first question is, does VS log reasons for closing unexpectedly? Can I find out what the offending reason behind this is? The main frustration is I don't know the cause, nor the cure.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The solution is a WPF Application with 3 library projects added in.

I have the following add-ins:

- Test Driven.NET 2.22.2468
- Xaml PowerToys

I can disable these, and then see if it still does it. But like before, it is not easily tested because it seems to randomly not work.

I use the properties tab quite a lot because we are using Click Once deployment and I go to the properties tab to publish the latest build.

Another possibility is that I have dual screens and I downloaded a utility called  [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) which lets you manage both screens better. Maybe that's jacking with VS and window messages are getting confused and killing the app process.

Comment: Are you using resharper or any other add-ins?

Comment: Can you give us some more details like what languages you are using and what project types?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how much memory VS is using, and how much you have available. If you are reaching close to 1.5GB memory usage, VS is under heavy pressure, and if you don't have at least 4GB on your box that would be the case as well.

Comment: Good point, but it even happens when i restart VS and the first thing i do is click properties. Also every other action in VS seems to work, seems to be some configuration issue